# makeindex doesn't use indexed words

Tags: indexing

When I use makeindex and try to index a word using

```
Hello \index{World}
```

the entry in the generated `\printindex` looks like

```
indexfile, 7
```

instead of

```
World, 7
```

-- This issue also happens when using `World\index{World}`.

The error seems to be somewhere before creating the .idx, as it looks like this

**doc.idx**

```
\indexentry{\@indexfile |hyperpage}{7}
```

**doc.ind**

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item indexfile , \hyperpage{7}

\end{theindex}
```

**Used packages**

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{showidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible as could be seen in this example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{showidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand\Index[1]{#1\index{#1}}
\begin{document}

This is my \Index{world} and my \Index{World}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

it creates a correct index:

[image]

I run `pdflatex->makeindex->pdflatex`. You have to create a complete example which shows your behaviour.

Comment: @ApoY2k: do not load the package `hyperref`. Does it help?

Comment: @ApoY2k: See my edited answer. It creates both the idnex and the margin notes for the index

Comment: @ApoY2K: we'll need a full example (one we can compile and which shows the issue).

Comment: @ApoY2k: you should run the example and not put the code into your document. Here is my output: http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/latex6.pdf And that is what you sjould also get

Comment: @ApoY2k -- note that @Herbert's example places `\usepackage{showidx}` *after* `\usepackage{hyperref}`.  order matters sometimes!